# AngularJS - How to test $scope initial value which are set up by a service

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

Let's says we have the following angular controller :

```
.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope, localStorageService) {
  $scope.vma = localStorageService.get('vma_vma') || 10;
}
```

It uses an external service (localStorageService) during initialization.
Basicelly localStorageService.get returns a previously stored value of 'vma_vma' or null if not present.

I've made a mock of localStorageService and the unit test looks like this:

```
describe('Controller: Ctrl', function () {
  // load the controller's module
  beforeEach(module('App', function($provide){
    localStorage = {};
    localStorage.get = jasmine.createSpy();
    localStorage.set = jasmine.createSpy();
    $provide.value('localStorageService', localStorage);
  }));

  var Ctrl,
    scope;
  // Initialize the controller and a mock scope
  beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    Ctrl = $controller(' Ctrl', {
      $scope: scope,
      localStorageService: localStorageService
    });
  }));
```

I'd like to be able to test 2 cases:

```
it('should get vma and return 10 when vma not present', function () {
    ???
    expect($scope.vma).toBe(10);
  });

  it('should get vma in localstorage when present', function () {
    ???
    expect($scope.vma).toBe(15);
  });
});
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create a mock localStorageService. Just to spy on the real one. But the solution is finally identical: just configure the mock/spy to return what you want **before** instantiating the controller:

```
describe('Controller: Ctrl', function () {
  var $controller,
      localStorageService,
      scope;

  beforeEach(module('App'));
  beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, $rootScope, _localStorageService_) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    $controller = _$controller_;
    localStorageService = _localStorageService_;
  }));

  it('should get vma and return 10 when vma not present', function() {
    // given no vma_vma in the local storage
    spyOn(localStorageService, 'get').and.returnValue(null);

    // when instantiating the controller
    $controller('Ctrl', {$scope: scope});

    // then its vma is initialized to 10
    expect($scope.vma).toBe(10);
    expect(localStorageService).toHaveBeenCalledWith('vma_vma');
  });

  it('should get vma in localstorage when present', function() {
    // given a vma_vma equal to 15 in local storage
    spyOn(localStorageService, 'get').and.returnValue(15);

    // when instantiating the controller
    $controller('Ctrl', {$scope: scope});

    // then its vma is initialized to 15
    expect($scope.vma).toBe(15);
    expect(localStorageService).toHaveBeenCalledWith('vma_vma');
  });
});
```